# If Column D Sheet 3 Matches a Value in Column C Sheet 1 Pull Data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have a list of domains in Column D on Sheet 3. If they match a value in column C of Sheet one. I want it to pull the same data thats in column A of sheet 1 and put that the relevant column on sheet 3

Comment: Please could you specifically document what you have tried so far and what bit you are stuck with so someone can answer your question

Answer (score 0):

In E1 on Sheet3:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(Sheet3!D1,Sheet1!C:C,0)),"")
```

This is assuming you have Excel 2007 or later. Otherwise it needs to be tweaked slightly.

Comment: Dangerous. Do you know the implications of omitting the third parameter of Match()? You may as well remove the IFError, because it will never fire.

Comment: What happens if the value being returned is a 0, considering only options should be "N", "Y" and "-"

Comment: Did you use the formula after I edited the Formula due to terylyn's comment?

Comment: @Zach the formula will return the found value. If there is no match, then it will return a blank. The formula will NOT ***evaluate*** the returned value. It does not matter if the result is "A", "B", "C", or "Y" or "N". If a match is found but the cell in the return column is empty, then a 0 will be returned. That's how Excel works. If you don't want to see that 0 then you need to catch that with other conditions. I suggest you move this fundamental Excel understanding question to Superuser.com because it is totally inappropriate for this programming site.